# Admin - Product edit default quantity 1

Tags: magento2

Since quantity field is not mandatory and I want that when ever product is added/updated quantity should be there

So there is two way of fix this, either I will make it mandatory or I set default value of quantity.

Can anyone help me do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a good idea to make quantity field mandatory. Because, in **virtual** and **downloadable products** quantity field set as `NULL`.

So, it is good to set a default field. You can do it by this:

Add a file in `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml`

code would be :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <modal name="advanced_inventory_modal">
        <fieldset name="stock_data">
            <field name="qty">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </modal>
</form>
```

Comment: It cleared a lot of things. Thanks